# Static blog / posts page issue

Tags: custom-post-types

In need of some help! I have changed my homepage to static, and my posts page to blogs, but whenever I do this I get an error of 'The site is experiencing technical difficulties' on the blog page.

Can anyone shed any light into this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your theme does not have a blog template. Try using a different theme to see if the issue gets fixed.